# Bootstrap navbar collapse a links with exception not floating left

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I want to make a float none in my application scss for all the a href from the navbar with the exception of the navbar-brand which is the "Home".

This is my application.html.erb:

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>

  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle= "collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse" >
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="top">
        
        
        <li><%= link_to "Products", products_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About the website", about_path %></li>


    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- the pull-right is like a float right -->
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
          
          <li><a><span class="current_user"> Current user: <%= @username %> </span></a></li>
          
          <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>

          <% else %>
          <li><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Log in</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-modal">Sign up</a></li>
        
          <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
      </div>
  
  </nav>
```

And this is my application.scss:

```css
@media (max-width: 769px) {
    #top{
        padding-top: 40px;
  
    }
}   

@media (max-width: 769px) {
    a:not(.navbar-brand){
        padding-top: 40px;
  float: none!important;
  
    }
}
```

The thing is that if I type:

```css
@media (max-width: 769px) {
        a{
            padding-top: 40px;
      float: none!important;
      
        }
    }
```

It does what I want, by putting float none it works like kind of float left aligning all the a href to the left. BUT, as I said, I don't want it to do the same with the Home a href that has the class navbar-brand. That's the reason why I've tried with no success the a:not(.navbar-brand).

Comment: Have you tried adding a separate rule for Home ---> .navbar-brand {float:left;}

Comment: I've tried if I put what you say:

@ media (max-width: 769px) {
    .navbar-brand{
        padding-top: 40px;
  float: left;
  
    }
}   

It stays the same as not putting anything at all

Comment: I found it @ovokuro by combining the suggestion of creating another media query for the class you gave me with this to achieve the final result: @ media (max-width: 769px) {
    .navbar-brand{
        line-height: 50px;
  
    }
}   
So if you'd like post this answer so I can validate it ;)

Comment: Glad you got it working, you were able to achieve the result without using float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a separate rule for your Home menu item with class `navbar-brand`.

```
@media (max-width: 769px) {
        a {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-brand {
            float: left;
        }
    }
```